# Asp.Net Mvc: ListBoxFor() support OptionGroups?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Does the helper method ListBoxFor() support option groups?

Eg: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup

Answer (score 7):

The `ListBoxFor()` `HtmlHelper` extension method does not support option groups. However, you can extend the `HtmlHelper` with a custom extension method that adds option group support.

Take a look at the following article:
[ASP.NET MVC – Extending the DropDownList to show the items grouped by a category](http://weblogs.asp.net/raduenuca/archive/2011/02/26/asp-net-mvc-extending-the-dropdownlist-to-show-the-items-grouped-by-a-category.aspx).

Comment: +1 - Your answer deserves to be accepted. Not only did you correctly answer the question, you provided a link to a solution.